# Technical name for path elements

Tags: java, path, classpath, buildpath

You hear terms like "classpath", "build path", etc. all the time, referencing a list of directories that something will look in for a particular reason.

Does anybody know the technical name for each item in these paths? **Path Element?!?!**

Yes - this is a programming question! I'm writing a classpath explorer object in Java and would like to know what to name my POJO property:

```
public class ClassPathExplorer
{
    private List<URI> pathElements; // ??????
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it is called as **path** or **resourcePath**

Comment: Eclipse's answer: "The build class path is a list of PATHS visible to the compiler when building the project."

Comment: So you're thinking `List<URI> paths`?

Comment: @AdamTannon yes List<URI> paths

Answer (score 0):

Generally they are called "File Paths".

> OS specific notes
>
> Being closely associated with the file system, the command-line
>   Classpath syntax depends on the operating system. For example:
>
> on all Unix-like operating systems (such as Linux and Mac OS X), the directory structure has a Unix syntax, with separate **file paths** separated by a colon (":").
>
> on Windows, the directory structure has a Windows syntax, and each **file path** must be separated by a semicolon (";").

Look at [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath_%28Java%29).